# What word can fit better than "view" in this context?

Tags: word-request

What word(s) fit better than **view** in the following sentence?

> The System shall allow any restaurant to **view** the customers who have ordered meals from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that this is the specification of a software system, I think there is nothing wrong with using *view* in this context. As an alternative, you could also use: *display*, *list*, or *access*.

Comment: If it is the specification of a software system, I think _access_ is more appropriate,for it's a privilege to access the system.

Comment: how about "access a list of customers"